# MapReduce function

Tags: mapreduce

Could some help me out?I am kind of naive in this area. I will appreciate if anyone helps me,

Assume that we have a relational database D containing tuples t with attributes t[A]. Write the pseudo code of Map and Reduce functions for retrieving all tuples with attribute t[A] > 100. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Map function takes in a single input from the set of all inputs, and returns a single output in the form of a key-value pair. The key represents a unique result after reduction, but since you only want one output (a single list of all tuples > 100), we will only use 1 key. Optionally, we don't have to return a key-value pair if we don't want it to contribute to the solution. We will use this to filter out tuples <= 100:

```py
def map(tuple):
    if tuple[A] > 100:
      return ("my_key", tuple[A])  # return the input as a value in the key-value pair
    else:
      return None  # don't return this key-value pair
```

The Reduce function takes in a key, and some subset of the values that were mapped to that key, and returns the subset of values aggregated into one value. In our case, our aggregation will simply be the identity function, because we don't want to reduce the list of valid tuples, we want to return them unchanged.

```py
def reduce(key, values):
  return (key, values)
```